# ASP.NET Core test: site can't be reached

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr

Just installed the latest bits for dotnet core on ubuntu server 14.4.4 https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu
The test webapp (dotnet run) is running on port:5000; however when trying to run from a webbrowser on the host machine (ubuntu-server is vm client machine) I get the message the site can't be reached. I have opened port 5000 on the Ubuntu server.

I must admit I also have nginx installed on this ubuntu server (and successfully get the default nginx page on port 80 - ASP.NET webapp doesn't work either, I tried following https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html probably the config isn't correct).

However for testing only with kestrel (on port 5000) I stopped the nginx webserver. First things first.

Anyone an idea what can go wrong testing with kestrel on port:5000?

Answer (score 4):

The Kestrel web server defaults to listening on **localhost**:5000, so if you haven't changed what host it listens on you won't be able to connect to it from a remote machine (or in your case, the host machine).

There are several ways that you can configure Kestrel to listen on a different host or port.  The simplest implementation would be to add the line `.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")` right after `.UseKestrel()` in your `Main` method.  This would make the application listen on all available IP addresses using port 5000.

**Update**

As [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) pointed out below, `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")` will allow you to use IPv6 addresses as well.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about IPv6.  I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Many thanks to all  of you. Works like a charm now.

When I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy can I leave .UseUrls("http://*:5000") in the Main file (or since I enter the system via nginx I suppose this is obsolete)?

Thanks.

Comment: As long as nginx can connect to localhost:5000, you should be able to remove the `UseUrls("http://*:5000")` I think.

Comment: I tried it and indeed it works without UseUrls.. when going via nginx. For production this is perfect. However for testing it can be handy talking directly to kestrel.
Thanks.